# Form Hidden Field Prints out Content to Webpage

Tags: php, html, forms, hidden-field

I have the following form code:

```
 <form action="pdf.php" method="POST" id="pdfform">
       <input type="hidden" name="htmlcontent" value="<?php echo $content ?>" >
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button back pdfsubmit">Download as PDF</a></li>

 </form>
```

However, what i realise is that the hidden field prints out the content to the HTML page as well, and there are some extra " and > which should not be there.

What i think could be the issue is because the role of the form is to send the html data to a PHP script to convert it to a PDF, the variable $content contains html code, for example: `<p>Test 3</p><p><img alt="Cancer" src="http://breakthroughs.cityofhope.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/lung-cancer.jpg" style="height:375px; width:500px" /></p>`

This could be one of the causes of the issue and the html prints out the extra "> at the end of the value inside the hidden form as well.

Anyone could find out the reason?

Comment: hi there, the file is in a .php, and im using a properly configured webserver. i think its something to do with the sanitization.

Comment: Replace any `"` inside `$content` with `&quot;`.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `htmlentities($string,ENT_QUOTES)` or `htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES)` to  print the HTML value in the hidden field?

Comment: @developerwjk as the content generated is dynamic, it is impossible to replace manually the "

Comment: There's a function called `str_replace`. (`htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` which Rasclatt mentioned would be better though)

Comment: thanks! the htmlentities solved all of the issues!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but have you considered using `jquery` to set the hidden field? for example (after ensuring you have no single quotes in your `$content` variable):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $('[name=htmlcontent]').val('<?php echo str_replace("'","`",$content) ?>');
<script>
```